# Are there any known microbes capable of living in almost pure carbon dioxide?

Tags: microbiology, metabolism

Some bioengineering is investigated in high carbon dioxide environments. Are there any microbes like bacteria or Archaea capable of living and multiplying in such environments?

Comment: It is not speculative to ask if a microbe can live in almost pure carbon dioxide.

Comment: @DavidJonsson Thank you for the edit, it improves the question immensely. In the previous form I would have certainly agreed with Willk.

Comment: Do you mean an atmosphere of co2/nitrogen like Earth had prior to the evolution of photosynthesis?  Presumably most of the bacteria from those days would be ok with a more or less pure co2 atmosphere, at least assuming they had access to water.

Comment: This is a much better question now! I think this could be even clearer if you made the 'Title' match the 'Body'. For example getting rid of the "almost pure" (which makes it sound like you're looking for something that can live on "dry ice" or in supercritical liquid CO₂) and being more specific — for example it seems like you might be interested in anoxic (oxygen free) environments ...

Comment: Also, are you only interested in organisms that are considered to be "extremophiles"? I found references to a non-extremophile that grows under Mars-like conditions ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These aren't technically extremophiles, but one paper identified twenty species of bacteria that grow under a low pressure, mostly CO₂ atmosphere<sup>1</sup>.

One relatively well studied species is [*Serratia liquefaciens*](https://microbewiki.kenyon.edu/index.php/Serratia_liquefaciens) (a Proteobacterium) that has been shown to grow under

> low temperature (0 °C), low pressure (0.7 kPa), and anoxic, CO2-dominated atmosphere-conditions intended to simulate the near-subsurface environment of Mars<sup>2</sup>.

### References:

1: [Schuerger, A. C., & Nicholson, W. L. (2016). Twenty species of hypobarophilic bacteria recovered from diverse soils exhibit growth under simulated martian conditions at 0.7 kPa. Astrobiology, 16(12), 964-976.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrew_Schuerger/publication/241433918_Synergistic_Effects_of_Low_Pressure_Low_Temperature_and_CO2_Atmospheres_Inhibit_the_Growth_of_Terrestrial_Bacteria_Under_Simulated_Martian_Conditions/links/5b804e55299bf1d5a724cdd3/Synergistic-Effects-of-Low-Pressure-Low-Temperature-and-CO2-Atmospheres-Inhibit-the-Growth-of-Terrestrial-Bacteria-Under-Simulated-Martian-Conditions.pdf)

2: [Fajardo-Cavazos, P., Morrison, M. D., Miller, K. M., Schuerger, A. C., & Nicholson, W. L. (2018). Transcriptomic responses of Serratia liquefaciens cells grown under simulated Martian conditions of low temperature, low pressure, and CO 2-enriched anoxic atmosphere. Scientific reports, 8(1), 1-10.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6175911/)

Answer (score 3):

[Capnophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capnophile) (from the Greek [*kapnós*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capno-), meaning smoke) are organisms that thrive in the presence of high concentrations of CO<sub>2</sub>.  Some of these organisms have a metabolic requirement for CO<sub>2</sub>.

Many organisms present in the cow rumen are capnophiles by necessity, as CO<sub>2</sub> is the major gas product of rumen fermentation (66% by molarity <sup>**1**</sup> ).  One such organism is *Mannheimia succiniciproducens*, which was shown to thrive in a pure CO<sub>2</sub> atmosphere when compared to pure N<sub>2</sub> and equimolar H<sub>2</sub>:CO<sub>2</sub>.

> Under N<sub>2</sub> atmosphere, cell growth and glucose consumption rates were much lower, suggesting that *M. succiniciproducens*, like other capnophilic bacteria, relies on a CO<sub>2</sub>-dependent metabolism. The glycolytic flux under CO<sub>2</sub> was four times greater than that obtained under N<sub>2</sub>.
>
> ...
>
> When H<sub>2</sub> was present, cell growth rate and the glycolytic flux were lower. However, the relative succinic acid flux increased by 30% under CO<sub>2</sub>-H<sub>2</sub>, and the relative formation rates of ATP and NADH were higher in the presence of H<sub>2</sub>.

Many pathogens are capnophiles, including species of *Campylobacter* <sup>**2**</sup>, *Neisseria gonorrhoeae* <sup>**3**</sup>, and *Haemophilus influenzae* <sup>**4**</sup>, though ideal culture conditions for these organisms call for CO<sub>2</sub> concentrations around 5 - 10%.

---

**References**

1. Hong SH, Kim JS, Lee SY, In YH, Choi SS, Rih JK, Kim CH, Jeong H, Hur CG, Kim JJ. The genome sequence of the capnophilic rumen bacterium *Mannheimia succiniciproducens*. *Nat Biotechnol*. 2004 Oct;22(10):1275-81.
2. Dykes GA, Moorhead SM. Survival of *Campylobacter jejuni* on vacuum or carbon dioxide packaged primal beef cuts stored at −1.5 °C. *Food Control*. 2001 Dec;12(8):553-7.
3. Platt DJ. Carbon dioxide requirement of *Neisseria gonorrhoeae* growing on a solid medium. *J Clin Microbiol*. 1976 Aug;4(2):129-32.
4. Langereis JD, Zomer A, Stunnenberg HG, Burghout P, Hermans PW. Nontypeable *Haemophilus influenzae* carbonic anhydrase is important for environmental and intracellular survival. *J Bacteriol*. 2013 Jun;195(12):2737-46.